# Sunset Date for Ui Service

Tags: google-apps-script

I know that apps script has a sunset date for the Ui Service and I am supposed to switch to HTML Service (not sure what that means... I guess I'll need to learn HTML Service now).  However, I feel like things are already starting to not work for my new functions.  I am still trying to build through Ui Service but my functions don't seem to be working properly.  Does anyone know anything about if things are already starting to shut down?

Thanks!

Comment: I suspect that there might be some problems already, but don't definitively know.  If you need to learn some HTML, that can only benefit you long term.  If you already know some HTML, hopefully your app isn't so large that it's going to take a lot of work to convert.  In any case, needing to switch is inevitable.

Answer (score 2):

The sunset date is June 30th, 2015.  The official documentation states that after the sunset service:

> Service will no longer appear in autocomplete, although existing scripts should still function.

[Apps Script Sunset Schedule](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/sunset?utm_campaign=htmlser-1214&utm_source=gadbc&utm_medium=blog)